# Multiple middleware with koa-router: "yield next" or "yield* next"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, generator, koa

With `koa-router`, when implementing [multiple middleware](https://github.com/alexmingoia/koa-router#multiple-middleware), why don’t I have to `yield* next`, but simply to `yield next`, as `next` is a generator as well?

[`koa` seems to be using `co`](https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/package.json#L23), and [after some fiddling](https://jsfiddle.net/s48n8unr/), it seems to be thanks to it, but could anyone confirm?

Is there any drawback of using `yield* next`, even if `yield next` would be enough? I find it less error-prone (for future devs at least).

Can help (although I don't fully get what's happening):

- https://github.com/alexmingoia/koa-router/blob/5.x/lib/router.js#L327
- https://github.com/alexmingoia/koa-router/blob/5.x/lib/router.js#L336

Comment: Have you read `co`'s documentation? [It does indeed state](https://github.com/tj/co#yieldables) that in can handle both generators and generator functions as "yieldables", so I assume that's simply what's happening here.